# After crash, meteor app doesn't work, even if I roll back to the working version?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Basically, when I make mistake somewhere and the app crashes, no matter what I do, it stays crashed. Deleting last changes, restarting the server, nothing... So, I have to create a new project, copy everything to a new project, and it works.

Help please, I have no idea what's going on.

Running the latest version of Meteor on Linux Mint 18.2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it stays crashed"?

Comment: Updating a servers code takes time. Ypu cant require it to *rework* immeadiately

Comment: Two hours passed, no changes, the same message: `Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:`.

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module './body.html'`

Comment: Problem is, there is `body.html` file in that folder. And it worked until I changed `main.js` file. Then it stopped working. I rollback the changes, still not working.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/re-installing meteor? Once upon a time I was getting strange behavior which I knew was out of character for Meteor. Removing and re-installing Meteor worked for me, although that was back when I was using Windows for development...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the message "Your app is crashing" in the browser, I think it has given up, and you need to refresh the brower. In fact, refreshing the browser is sometimes necessary anyway.

Meteor detects changes to files pretty well, but sometimes struggles with new, deleted or moved files, and you may need to restart meteor and refresh the browser. You shouldn't need to copy to a new project.

Comment: If restarting meteor is not enough, sometimes deleting `meteor/.local` folder or executing `meteor reset` might help. That should avoid in all cases having to copy to a new project.

Comment: I tried refreshing obviously, it's not working. But I think the deleting the folder worked. Thanks ;)